# Android: OnClicklistener

Tags: android, onclick, clicklistener

i have a problem... I have different textviews with a listener. Like these ones:

```
    help_modul.setOnClickListener(this);
    help_timetable.setOnClickListener(this);
    help_credits.setOnClickListener(this);
    help_todo.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Here is my listener:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

 String temp=   v.getId(); // DOESNT WORK
 Toast.makeText(this, temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

In my listener I want to differ between my textview.... For example Click on Textfield "a "do that, if a click on another textfield do another operation..

Have u any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.textview1:
        doSomething1();
        break;
      case R.id.textview2
        doSomething2();
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @user1197351 Glad :) If this is what you were looking for it will be great if you can mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

You could 
a) make InstanceListeners such as:

```
TextView(context).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        // ...
        Log.d(TAG, "I'm doing stuff");
    }
}
```

or you could 
b) check the instances of your textview:

```
@Override public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == mGirlTextView) {
        // Do Stuff
        Log.d(TAG, "I'm Forever alone");
    } else if (view == mBoyTextView) {
        // Do moar stuff
        Log.d(TAG, "Let's grab a beer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch case

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.help_modul:
        // do code
        break;
    case R.id.help_timetable:
        // do code
        break;
    case R.id.help_credits:
        // do code
        break;
    case R.id.help_todo:
        // do code
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this statement  `String temp=   v.getId(); // DOESNT WORK` you are getting the id of view which is of datatype `long` and then assigning to the `String` variable, which may be correct but it is bad approach.

**Use this improved code instread**:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == help_modul.getId())
    {
        /*do some work on the click*/
    }
    else if(v.getId() == help_timetable.getId())
    {
        /*do some work on the click*/
    }
    else if(v.getId() == help_credits.getId())
    {
        /*do some work on the click*/
    }
    else if(v.getId() == help_todo.getId())
    {
        /*do some work on the click*/
    }
}
```